# Generate frames from days

Tags: r, date, type-conversion

In my data set the days have this format:

```
day
2000-01-01 00:00:00
2000-01-01 01:00:00
2000-01-01 02:00:00
2000-01-01 03:00:00
```

We call the dataframe day.

I want to generate a dataframe for days and I am using this:

```
n=12
day <- as.Date( tail( day$day , 1 ) , format = "Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )+1:n
```

However the problem is that this gives me 2000-01-01 instead of 2000-01-01 03:00:00. It doesn't includes the hours only the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these will work. You are also missing a `%` before the `Y` in your call to `as.Date`. Note that the integer unit of these datatypes is seconds, so to add an hour to a date/time you need to add multiples of 3600 seconds to the date:

```
n=12
strptime( "2000-01-01 03:00:00" , format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )+(1:n)*3600
as.POSIXct( "2000-01-01 03:00:00" , format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )+(1:n)*3600
```

I recommend the `as.POSIXct` method. `strptime` converts character vectors to class `POSIXlt`. I am not sure why, but I think many people prefer `POSIXct` over `POSIXlt`.

```
as.POSIXct( tail( days$day , 1 ) , format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )+(1:n)*3600
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the as.Date() call, change your addition line, and it will work:

```
> format(day + as.difftime(1, units='day'), format='%c')
2000-01-02 00:00:00
2000-01-02 01:00:00
2000-01-02 02:00:00
2000-01-02 03:00:00
```